# Can I have Win10 on NVMe and Ubuntu on SSD in same laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, installation

Ok! I have **512GB NVMe SSD** preinstalled in my laptop and as I have a slot for HD, I bought **Crucial BX500 2TB 3D NAND SATA 8.89 cm (2.5-Inch) Internal SSD** which I'm about to install in an Asus Tuf gaming laptop. On NVMe I have installed Windows 10 but due to my academic requirements, I need to use Ubuntu for Python development. I am very apprehensive as it is my first time using Ubuntu and I don't know how to go about it.

Here, are my 3 questions:

1. Can I install Ubuntu on my second secondary storage device?
2. If so, then how am I supposed to do it?
3. How booting process will look if I will have both Windows and Ubuntu? That is, do I will option of selecting login into Win10 or Ubuntu when my laptop boots?

NOTE: I don't want to install VM on Win10 for Ubuntun nor do I want to access Ubuntu from a portable USB.

Comment: I am very apprehensive as it is my first time using Ubuntu and I don't know how to go about it.    .........  I would definitely re-consider using a VM.  You can back up a VM and recover if things go wrong. Much much better for learning Lnux.

Comment: In this case I must second @John 's opinion.

Answer (score -2):

> Can I install Ubuntu on my second secondary storage device?

Yes, of course. It's called dual-booting.

> If so, then how am I supposed to do it?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi is a good starting point to understand the UEFI boot process and its requirements. Some answers there could use a refreshing/update but the general gist is still valid.

N.B. - You still need to understand partitioning, how to identify your additional drive, the target for Ubuntu installation and disable Windows' Fast Startup feature and properly shutdown Windows before starting the Ubuntu installation. Later you may or may not need to open UEFI settings - Boot menu and adjust the OS boot order to "Ubuntu" if the installer couldn't do it automatically.

> How booting process will look if I will have both Windows and Ubuntu? That is, do I will option of selecting login into Win10 or Ubuntu when my laptop boots?

The typical boot process via Grub is also mentioned in the above Q&A and yes, obviously, you'll have an option to boot Ubuntu (default) or Windows among other options in the Grub menu. You can also at any time change the boot order in UEFI settings to boot Windows directly.

> I don't want to install VM on Win10

A VM is actually the best and safest option for the Ubuntu usage you mentioned. The sad truth is if you felt the need to ask this question then perhaps you should learn some very basic concepts before attempting to install an OS, let alone two in dual-boot.

Should you decide to actually learn from the above Q&A you're on the right path to a successful installation but there can be unforeseen problems specific to your hardware. No such problems are expected with virtualization.